# Visual Studio 2013 remote development

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've a Sharepoint 2013 installation in a Server 2008 machine.
My development machine runs Windows 7 and I've got Visual Studio 2013 installed.

I want to create a sharepoint 2013 project but I have this error:

> The required version of sharepoint foundation 2013 or sharepoint server 2013 is not installed on this system. sharepoint must be installed on the local system

Do I have to install SP locally? Can't i just develop against a remote installation?

Answer (score 9):

You can create SharePoint 2013 project in your Visual studio 2013 without installing SharePoint on your local machine.

Please follow below steps : 
Go to the server where SharePoint 2013 is installed and follow steps from 1 to 3

1. Go to Run and type "regedit"
2. Navigate towards HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office
3. Right click on 15.0 and click Export. Save the exported file

Now go to your machine where sharepoint is not installed and follow below steps:

1. Now open Registry on your machine
2. Import the 15 directory which was exported from SharePoint server
3. Open Powershell
4. Run this command

   Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\web server extensions\15.0\" -Name "Location" -Value "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\"

Now open visual studio 2013 and you will be able to create SharePoint 2013 project without error.

Comment: I set this up perfectly thanks to your advice - and then installed VS 2013 Update 3, and now VS won't let me create or open a SharePoint project. Has anyone got this to work with Update 3?

Comment: After Modified the registry VS2013 is working fine thank you kaplesh

Comment: In my case copying the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office hive wasn't necessary. Also, manually adding values into HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\web server extensions\15.0\ using regedit didn't do the trick, but using powershell did. I don't get how is this different from using regedit directly, but it worked. Thanks.

Comment: This worked fine (with the addion of @Anna Komissar. 

Is there a way to add Workflows in the new created project? At the moment Visual Studio complains that there is no Site URL. I tried to enter some URL but I always got the message, that there remote connections are not possible...

-thx

Answer (score 3):

I perfectly agree with Kalpesh answer,but i have to admit that you need one more PowerShell command:
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\web server extensions\15.0\" -Name "SharePoint" -Value "Installed"
After that you need to run from administrator your Visual Studio 2013 and all will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, you can only develop (including debugging) on the same machine where SP is installed. If you just want your code to be available outside that machine, you can use [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs) (formerly TFS) or something like [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)

Comment: I don't know specifically with SP 2013, which is why I haven't answered, but at least in SP 2010 you could remotely develop and remotely debug. I've never done the former, but I have done the latter plenty of times.

Comment: RJ, I think that only pertains to client OM code. Not Server OM. So it really depends.

Comment: Definitely debugged server side code remotely. See these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188364/sharepoint-how-to-connect-remotely-to-production-server http://lemonharpy.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/remote-debugging-sharepoint-2010-solutions/ and for sandboxed solutions there's always this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh370987.aspx it's just not quite as convenient as developing on an SP server.

Comment: That's interesting, I learned something new today.