# Remote development to SharePoint 2013 with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Referring to the following question: [Visual Studio 2013 remote development](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92035/visual-studio-2013-remote-development)

I have tried this method to setup my environment for remote development to my on-premises SharePoint server. However, it does not work. And Google hasn't got me anywhere so far.

I get the following error when I try to create a new SharePoint project in Visual Studio 2013 on my local machine:
[image: Project creation error]

So my question is: **Can i develop SharePoint projects remotely from my Windows 8.1 machine that is running Visual Studio 2013 Pro, to my Windows Server 2012 server hosting the SharePoint services?**

Referring to the question posted already: I have tried to extract the registry and import it to my local machine and run the PowerShell command. No luck, same error.

I am running:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: New project dialog]

The project templates in the SharePoint Solutions section **do not** support remote development while the projects templates in the Apps section do.

Comment: Short, simple and fast. Just the way I like it! Thank you! :)