# Cannot Connect to targeted site - Sharepoint 2013 Visual Studio 2013 - Remote Development

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I wanted to develop solutions for Sharepoint 2013. I have visual studio 2013 installed on a windows 7 machine and Share point 2013 installed on Win 2008 R2 server. Both systems in the same LAN. I am able to access sharepoint through browser like so `http://sp-production/sites`.

Since I could not install share point 2013 on my Win 7 machine I tried for remote development. I have searched on Google and found this [SO Post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92035/visual-studio-2013-remote-development). I have configured according to the post and now I can create Apps for Share point.

When I try to create a Share Point Project (Empty Project for example) in Visual Studio 2013 it pops up the dialog asking for the site. I entered `http://sp-production/sites/IT` and clicked on validate. This has thrown an error

[image: Screenshot of the error I get]

I searched for a solution to this and came across various posts that said editing the hosts file and adding a lien there with the IP address of the Sharepoint Server and the Sharepoint server name and hence I have added `192.168.2.9    sp-production`.

I have also tried to add my own PC IP tot he hosts file but given the name of the sharepoint server but the error still persists.

But still I get the same error that is depicted in the screen shot above.

Kindly advice on resolving this.

*Note: My Sharepoint is a fresh installation without any sort of customisation (connected to Active Directory) and I am the only user on Sharepoint currently with site administrator privileges on the specified URL*

Answer (score 0):

Typically for SharePoint development, Visual Studio is installed on the server that is also running SharePoint.  Very often this is on a virtual server that is dedicated to the developer, and is in essence a "private farm", which has no connection to the production SharePoint farm.

*The answer you link to involves creating registry entries designed to fool VS into thinking SP is actually installed on the same machine.*

IMHO this is not a good practice.  Even in [Microsoft's own instructions on how to set up a SharePoint development environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx), the basic steps are:

- Install the OS (Windows Server)
- Install SharePoint
- Install Visual Studio

This would seem to me very strong evidence that the intended setup is to have VS on the same server as SP.

Additionally: Apps are the *only* type of project you actually *can* do remotely.  You should be able to create an "App for SharePoint" type project on a machine that does not have SharePoint installed even *without* doing all that registry trickery.