# Sharepoint Workflows with Sharepoint Online on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio

When trying to create a new empty sharepoint project, I am getting this error:

```
The required version of sharepoint foundation or sharepoint server is not installed on this system. Sharepoint must be installed on the local system to develop sharepoint solutions
```

The folder is simply created in the chosen directory with no content whatsoever.

I am trying to run on a local machine. I downloaded developer tools and Sharepoint foundation 2013. But still I am getting the error. When Sharepoint foundation installs it automatically opens Visual Studio 2013 in administrator mode, but when trying to create a new empty project, same error pops up.

What can I try? I only found an option where you try to trick the computer into thinking that Sharepoint is actually installed when it's not: [See link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92035/visual-studio-2013-remote-development), but I prefer not to go for this option if there is another way!

Also does perhaps Visual Studio 2012 work better when connecting with Sharepoint Online to create workflows? Because in that case I would try to download it and try from there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop online SharePoint workflow You can't create a SharePoint Solution as on-prem you only have an option is to create an `APP` project as shown below

[image]

you should also be aware of you can't use code behind to develop online workflow in visual studio, so you should use `Calling RESTful Services`

To create online workflow check this [article](http://satalyst.com/creating-list-workflow-sharepoint-online-2013-using-visual-studio/)

See also MSDN article for [Develop SharePoint 2013 workflows using Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163199(v=office.15).aspx#bkm_Debug)

If you are not familiar with `RESTful Services` try to use SharePoint Designer to build your workflow.

Comment: I want to move a humongous document library to a different site collection on the same office 365. Im afraid Sharepoint Designer wont be useful in this case. I don't seem to be able to connect to Sharepoint Online and create a code workflow for it, havent managed a way so I would appreciate any of your suggestions. But do you think that what I need to do can be done using Rest services?

Answer (score 0):

You can create SharePoint 2013 project in your Visual studio 2013 without installing SharePoint on your local machine.

Please follow below steps : Go to the server where SharePoint 2013 is installed and follow steps from 1 to 3

Go to Run and type "regedit"
Navigate towards HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office
Right click on 15.0 and click Export. Save the exported file
Now go to your machine where sharepoint is not installed and follow below steps:

Now open Registry on your machine
Import the 15 directory which was exported from SharePoint server
Open Powershell
Run this command

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\web server extensions\15.0\" -Name "Location" -Value "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\"
Now open visual studio 2013 and you will be able to create SharePoint 2013 project without error.

Let us know if this helped?

Comment: Thanks for your help. However Im afraid your solution did not work. Besides, I installed Visual Studio 2013 on a server which has Sharepoint installed. From an empty sharepoint project that I tried to create I was not able to see the components of the site that I tried to connect to. From a sharepoint app I have no idea how to create a workflow, if it is even possible. My task is to move a very large document library consisting of document sets each with hundreds of documents. In all the document library consists of over 100,000 documents. Any help would be appreciated