# The required version of SharePoint Foundation or Server is not installed

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, web-part, visual-studio-2015

I have SharePoint server 2013 installed on the server, on the other server is 2010 (but I do not have access to the server) and I would like to make a project for it in 2013, is there a way to get around this with the current 2013?

[image]

Comment: you want to create a project with visual studion 2015 and sharepoint 2013 but want to deploy it for sharepoint 2010, right?

Comment: Yes, quite right.

Comment: In theory you can just use Sharepoint DLL (From 2010) but you will not be able to test it in SP2013. Best way for SPDevelopment is to have machine with Sharepoint installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go lower to higher version but i am not sure if you can go from higher to lower. I would create a development machine( as Marek recommend as well) may be create a VM on your pc and develop and test the solution their.

Here is good hack, the post mentioned SharePoint 2013 but you can go SharePoint 2010 and export the registry for 14 and import on your local machine.

[Visual Studio 2013 remote development](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92035/visual-studio-2013-remote-development)